# Execute distinct queries stored in table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-cursor

I have a table `the_tbl` that has a column `SQL Statement`, with different SQL queries on each row.

[image: the_tbl: table described here]

```
******************************************************
Col1 ||  Col2  || SQL_Statement
******************************************************
A    |     1   |  SELECT * FROM the_tbl
B    |     2   |  SELECT Col 2 from the_tbl
C    |     3   |  SELECT * FROM the_tbl
******************************************************
```

I am using a cursor to iterate through each row and print results of each statement.

```
DECLARE @execute_queries nvarchar(max)  

DECLARE my_cur CURSOR FOR 
SELECT the_tbl.SQL_Statement FROM the_tbl;

OPEN my_cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM my_cur INTO @execute_queries;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    EXECUTE(@execute_queries) 
    FETCH NEXT FROM my_cur INTO @execute_queries
END;
CLOSE my_cur
```

I am hoping to execute the cursor in such a way that if a SQL query has been executed already then it should not be repeated.

For example if you look at rows 1 & 3 on the_tbl, query `SELECT * FROM the_tbl` is repeated. How can I stop this from happening? 
Can I use a If statement within the Cursor?  so that it wont repeat a same query that has been executed already?

Comment: you can use distinct to avoid duplicates `SELECT distinct the_tbl.SQL_Statement FROM the_tbl;`

Comment: Don't forget to deallocate that cursor... and you could use fast_forward on your cursor too for this use case. Aside from that @JamieD77 comment is what you are looking for. Lastly, this seems like a scary thing to do. I'd check the permissions on that table to make sure people can't update your SQL_Statement column to something corrupt.

Comment: Your problem sounds quite strange. Why do you have duplicates in your table? If it's SQL statements, isn't order of execution critical?

Comment: @JamieD77, Andrea thanks for your replies. Both your suggestions are working fine :) Just wondering which one would be more optimal from performance point of view?

Comment: I completely agree with @scsimon here; storing T-SQL statement in a table and just executing them sounds like an awful idea. It'll probably be wide open to SQL Injection.

Comment: @gurpreetsingh performance wise, `DISTINCT` is exactly what this was created for, and is more legible. Just a thought. `GROUP BY` without an aggregate isn't very common.

Comment: @scsimon thank for the clarification and edits to my question earlier  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `GROUP BY` statement to remove duplicates:

```
SELECT the_tbl.SQL_Statement FROM the_tbl GROUP BY the_tbl.SQL_Statement;
```

So your code should be:

```
DECLARE @execute_queries nvarchar(max)  

DECLARE my_cur CURSOR FOR 
SELECT the_tbl.SQL_Statement FROM the_tbl GROUP BY the_tbl.SQL_Statement; --Added GROUP BY

OPEN my_cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM my_cur INTO @execute_queries;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    EXECUTE(@execute_queries) 
    FETCH NEXT FROM my_cur INTO @execute_queries
END;
CLOSE my_cur
DEALLOCATE my_cur
```

As pointed out in the comments you can achieve the same result using `DISTINCT`:

```
DECLARE @execute_queries nvarchar(max)  

DECLARE my_cur CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DISTINCT the_tbl.SQL_Statement FROM the_tbl; --Added DISTINCT

OPEN my_cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM my_cur INTO @execute_queries;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    EXECUTE(@execute_queries) 
    FETCH NEXT FROM my_cur INTO @execute_queries
END;
CLOSE my_cur
DEALLOCATE my_cur
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non cursor way of doing it

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/XRDY13726)**</kbd>

```
declare @execute_queries nvarchar(max) 
select @execute_queries=stuff((select distinct ';'
+ the_tbl.SQL_Statement FROM the_tbl 
for xml path('')),1,1,'')
execute( @execute_queries)
```